# Laravel 5.6 - Objeto no se guarda en la BDD

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una función que crea y guarda un objeto. Si ejecuto esta función crea el objeto (porque le asigna una ID) pero al hacer el `save()` no lo guarda en la base de datos.

Si utilizo el mismo código en tinker, si que lo guarda.

Además, cuando ejecuto la función, la ID que le asigna al objeto, aunque no lo guarde en la BDD, queda registrado porque no lo vuelve a repetir.

**Ejemplo:** Ejecuto la función y el objeto se le asigna la ID 5. Ejecuto el código en tinker, se le asigna la ID 6. Si voy a la base de datos, el único que existe de los es el ID 6.

Código en cuestión:

```
$espacio = new \App\Post();
$espacio->type = 'espacio-retiro';
$espacio->status = 'draft';
$espacio->author_id = "1159";
$espacio->title = "asdasdasdsad";
$espacio->description = "asdasdasdasdsadadsd";
$espacio->post_name = "a1112222223";
$espacio->save();
```

El `save()` desde la función y desde tinker devuelven `True`.

No entiendo porque desde la función no funciona correctamente, se supone que el contexto no debe afectar, ¿verdad?

Comment: este codigo esta dentro de una importación,  he seguido exactamente esta documentación: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html

Comment: Agrega un [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código.